# How to give Class to child process in python?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pipe

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def f(a1):
    print a1.name
    a1.conn2.send('why!?!?!?!?!!?!??')
    a1.conn2.close()

class test1:
    name = 'this is name in class'
    conn1,conn2 = Pipe()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1 = test1

    p = Process(target=f, args=(a1,))
    p.start()
    print a1.conn1.recv()
    p.join()
```

I have to give multiple argument to child process and pipe communication 
between parent and child.

So I try to give Class to child process include pipe.

But this code's child process can't send anything.

So parent process hanging at recv().....

How can solve this? help me plz.....T.T

PS : This is python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Windows:

You are initializing the Pipes statically inside the class `test1`, so when the new process is created (when you call `start()`), the `test1` class is recreated and with it the Pipe. That means your function running in the new process is using a different Pipe altogether.

This can be solved by creating the Pipes in an ***instance*** of `test1` (or passing the connection directly):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def f(a1):
    print a1.name
    a1.conn2.send('why!?!?!?!?!!?!??')
    a1.conn2.close()

class Test1(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'this is name in class'
        self.conn1, self.conn2 = Pipe()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1 = Test1()

    p = Process(target=f, args=(a1,))
    p.start()
    print a1.conn1.recv()
    p.join()
```